# Как получить координаты 3D модели, нажимая на модель мышкой (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно получить точку размещения модели (центр).

Answer (score 1):

прикрепляйте mouseclick event на ваш 3d model.с помощью самого объекта (object sender) можете сделать что хотите.